# Cache do JSON API no Xcode

Tags: json, wordpress, ios, objective-c, cache

Quero fazer cache do JSON API do meu Wordpress em meu app. Quero um cache dos `tableview cells` e `UIWebView` para quando estiver em modo avião ou desligado ou com mau sinal, o usuário ainda possa ver. Eu tentei fazer o cache com AFNetworking e NSURLCache mas não sei como. Como posso formatar AFNetworking ou NSURLCache para isto?

```
 NSURL *blogURL =[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://purpledrop.org/api/get_recent_summary/"];

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

 NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:blogURL  completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
//this app would crash without this code below in airplane mode or no wifi
if (jsonData ==nil) {
    return;
}

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

self.blogPosts = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *blogPostArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in  blogPostArray) {
    BlogPost *blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    blogPost.author = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];
    blogPost.thumbnail = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    blogPost.date = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
    blogPost.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]];
    [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost]; 
      }  
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self.tableView reloadData];    
                      });  
               }];
             [task resume];
           }
```

Comment: Oi cara me vai ajudar ou criticar. Eu sei como falar e ler. Mas ninguém me respondeu em inglês então fui aqui. Também queria ajudar este site porque não tem tantas perguntas quanto o site normal.

Comment: Ok, desculpe o mal entendido. E a resposta do Ricardo, não ajudou? . . . . Infelizmente iOS não é minha área, se fosse cache no WP podia ser. Boa sorte! . . . .PS: deletei meu comentário anterior, que mencionava o [post duplicado no site em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027471/offline-json-caching-ios).

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é você fazer cache dessas informações em um banco de dados local (SQLite ou CoreData) e fazer uma verificação de se o usuário tem conexão. Pelo próprio AFNetworking tem uma classe para isso:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

}

- (BOOL)connected {
    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}
```